# How can I unroot OG Droid Gingerbread to latest stock firmware

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid, cyanogenmod, unrooting

I want to unroot my Motorola Droid from CyanogenMod 7 RC (Gingerbread 2.3.3) to the latest version of stock Froyo.

I've been told there's some complications that can happen because of the new file system used (ext4 instead of yaffs).

Are there any instructions on the internet on how to do this? Reading all these unroot instructions are confusing. So many different ways and some don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to post a complete answer, but [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=932196) has everything I was going to say and it would take me too long to reproduce it :P.  [This post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11902461&postcount=5) is basically a shortened version of the other, if you prefer that, but it seems you'd prefer more detail.

Comment: I essentially downloaded RSD Lite 4.9 and downloaded/flashed an SBF file from http://www.peteralfonso.com/p/downloads.html I had to use FRG22D not the latest since those are debug builds. After that my phone works fine.